# have a dynamic height with error message

Tags: html, jsf, height

Sorry JSF is not my main language

I have a JSF Composite Component named validatedInputTextQuestion. It's essentially a bold label, then a textbox on first line.. next line is a note about said inputText, and below that is where my validation message would show.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <b>#{cc.attrs.questionLabel} : </b>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.bindingValue}" id="checkSpecs" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" size="15" label="#{cc.attrs.errorLabel}">
        <f:validateLength minimum="#{cc.attrs.minLength}" maximum="#{cc.attrs.maxLength}" />
    </h:inputText>
    <br />
    <b>#{cc.attrs.notes}</b>
    <br />
    <h:message for="checkSpecs" style="color:red" />
    <br />
</cc:implementation>
```

not all instances of this template have a note. but when I test out this page there is a extra break  above my error message. Which is to be expected as that is what my template does... What i'd like to know is if there is a dynamic way of having this note attribute take up space if there is data.. I know in Silverlight I could use a grid and set a row definition height of Auto... or use a boolean to visibilty converter, but i can't find the equivalent in JSF. Can someone help point me to a solution for this?